# Get message 'deprecated APIs' in GoBackN client/server programs

Tags: java

My S/W simulation of GoBack N protocol gives warning- `[deprecation] readLine() in DataInputStream has been deprecated` (while reading from streams) while running both client & server programs .Please tell me a solution.Is there any alternative for `readLine()`? Here is my client/server programs

```
    //Server Program
    import java.io.*;
    import  java.net.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    public class gobacksender
    {
       public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
        {

    //Establishing connection
       ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(4444);
            System.out.println("Waiting for connection........");
        Socket s=ss.accept();
        System.out.println("Connected to client at:"+s);

      DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        DataInputStream in1=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
          PrintStream p=new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
    int sptr=0,sws=8,i,ano,nf,n;
    String sbuf[]=new String[8];
    String ch,ch1;


              System.out.println("Enter the no.of frames");
            nf=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
            p.println(nf);

        if(nf<=sws-1)
        {
          System.out.println("Enter the "+nf+" messages to be send");
        for(i=1;i<=nf;i++)
        {
             sbuf[sptr]=in.readLine();
            p.println(sbuf[sptr]);
             sptr=++sptr%8;
        }
        sws-=nf;
        do
        {
            ano=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        System.out.println("Received acknowledgement for:"+ano);
        System.out.println("Retransmitting...............");
            for(i=ano-1;i<nf;i++)
            p.println(i);
                    ch1=in1.readLine();
        }while(ch1.equals("yes"));
        sws+=nf;
            }
            else
            {
            System.out.println("the no.of frames exceed window size");
                }
        ano=Integer.parseInt(in1.readLine());
        System.out.println("Acknowledgement received for"+ano+"frames");
        s.close();
        }
        }

    //Client Program
    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;
    import java.lang.*;
    public class gobackreceiver
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception
        {
    //Connection establishment
        Socket s=new Socket("localhost",4444);
              System.out.println("Connected to server at:"+s);
    DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(System.in);
        DataInputStream in1=new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    PrintStream p=new PrintStream(s.getOutputStream());
           String rbuf[]=new String[8];
    int i,rptr=0,rws=8,nf,n;
           String ch,ch1;
    do
    {
            nf=Integer.parseInt(in1.readLine());
    System.out.println("No.of messages",nf);
    if(nf<rws)
    {
    for(i=1;i<=nf;i++)
    {
         rbuf[rptr]=in1.readLine();
         rptr=++rptr%8;
         System.out.println("The received frame"+(rptr+1)+"is:"+rbuf[rptr]);
    }
    rws-=nf;
    do
    {
    System.out.println("Enter the nak number");
    n=Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
    if((1<=n)&&(n<=nf))
    {
    p.println(n);
    for(i=n;i<nf;i++)
    {
    rbuf[i]=in1.readLine();
    System.out.println("the received frame"+i+"is;"+rbuf[i]);
    }
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("Invalid nak");
    }
    System.out.println("Anymore frames lost?");
    ch1=in.readLine();
    p.println(ch1);
    }while(ch1.equals("yes"));
    System.out.println("Ack sent");
    p.println(rptr+1);
    rws+=nf;
    }
    else
    break;
    ch=in.readLine();
    }while(ch.equals("yes"));
    s.close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: The words are *'deprecated'* and *'deprecation'.* Error messages must be quoted accurately. Your question is answered by the Javadoc. -1

Answer (score 0):

Copied from the [Java API Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html):
Deprecated. 
This method does not properly convert bytes to characters. As of JDK 1.1, the preferred way to read lines of text is via the BufferedReader.readLine() method. Programs that use the DataInputStream class to read lines can be converted to use the BufferedReader class by replacing code of the form:

```
     DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(in);
```

with:

```
     BufferedReader d
          = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
```

If you get such warnings, your first look should always be on the API or at least googling..